# Refresh a particular DIV after updating username in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, page-refresh

I am using angularJS model to edit the user profile (using ng-click). After edit, user information will be update at the server(using http POST) side and get a success reply. The returned data will be stored back into the player object.

However, my user's edited profile is not update immediately unless the page is refreshed. I am using ng-bind to display user's information but no avail.

I also tried to use, use jQuery just to refresh as single div, which contain user's info bit no use as well.

please advise me.

Thank you all.

**Player info display div (HTML):**

```
<div class="span4" id="playerProfile">
    <image ng-src="{{player.gravatar}}"; width = 80px; height= 100px;/> <br> <br> 
    <div ng-model="player.nickname"style="text-align: center;" id="heading">{{<span ng-bind="player.nickname">}}</span></div>
    <br>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
           <button class="btn-small btn-primary span12" ng-click="show_panel()">Edit</button><br/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Controller Code (JS file)**

```
$scope.update_player_profile = function($event){  

    var data = {"nickname":$scope.player.nickname,
                "professional":$scope.player.professional,
                "about":$scope.player.about,
                "tags":$scope.player.tags,
                "gender":$scope.player.gender};

    $http.post("/jsonapi/update_player_profile", data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            window.console.log(data);
            $scope.player = data;
            console.log($scope.player.nickname)
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });          

    //$("playerProfile").load("profile")

};
```

Comment: We probably need to see more of your code to help you.  Ideally, you would set up a minimal fiddle or plunker showing the problem.  Are you using more than one controller?  Is update_player_profile() defined on the same controller as the player info HTML?

Comment: What is the post returning to success? What is that data object returned? Does it contain nickname attr?

Comment: @MarkRajcok, both function update_player_profile() and player Json fetch reside in the same controller called PlayerController. As for setting JS fiddle, I am sorry that I unable to do since it requires server data fetching. I tries to create one but failed.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne, player data object is being returned and it does contain nickname attribute. After it returns, player.nickname is not update seamlessly but it requires page refresh.

Comment: Use $timeout to fake out an $http request in your fiddle:  `$timeout(function() { $scope.player = {your faked data here} }, 2000);`  With that you should be able to reproduce your problem.